# Bond Communications Framework Deprecated

Tags: c#, idl, grpc, bond

I´ve used the bond-compiler gbc to create some object and a service definition for me:

```
namespace Something;
struct SomeStruct
{
    0: string SomeName;
}
struct SomeResponse
{
    0: string ResponseString;
}
service SomeService
{
    SomeResponse DoSomething(SomeStruct);
}
```

The compiler generated a class definition `Something_services.cs` with this Signature:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("gbc", "0.8.0.0")]
public abstract class SomeServiceServiceBase : ISomeService, global::Bond.Comm.IService
```

I was wondering about the IService Interface and wanted to know more about this and came to the Bond Communications Framework Doku (https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_comm.html). The first thing to read was, that Bond.Comm is deprecated and you should use Bond-over-gRPC (https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_over_grpc.html) instead.

I have two questions:

- Does someone know, why this is depracted but by default still used by the compiler?
- Is there someone who can explain the difference between Bond.Comm and Bond-over-gRPC?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

And a third question occured: How to use the --grpc-flag mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: I'm not planning to answer the "Is there someone who can explain the difference between Bond.Comm and Bond-over-gRPC?" as part of this. It feels like it's a different enough question that it warrants its own question and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bond C# gRPC bindings first shipped in Bond C# 5.3.0, which was released on 2017-04-14. You will need to upgrade all your Bond NuGet packages to 5.3.0 to start using it.

You are seeing the compiler generate the Comm files by default because you're using a version earlier than 5.3.0.

As noted in the [changelog](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#530-2017-04-12) for the 5.3.0 release (and the Bond Comm 0.11.0 release), Bond Comm files are no longer generated by default for C#. To keep using Bond Comm C#, you'll need to start passing `--comm` to gbc. There's an [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/blob/581d88632e0ad8b2fc87f5674273f613e78af752/examples/cs/comm/pingpong/pingpong.csproj#L39) that shows what change is needed.

If you want to start using the C# gRPC bindings, you'll need to pass the `--grpc` option. The [gRPC example](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/blob/581d88632e0ad8b2fc87f5674273f613e78af752/examples/cs/comm/grpc_pingpong/grpc_pingpong.csproj#L48) shows how to do this as well.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I´ll keep looking :)